# Что означает CONSTRAINT и REFERENCES в данном запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

Таблица Players

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players] (
[Id]       INT        NOT NULL,
[Name]     NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Age]      INT        NOT NULL,
[Position] NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[TeamId]   INT        NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Players_Teams] FOREIGN KEY ([TeamId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Teams] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: Внешний ключ, говорящий, что в поле TeamId может быть либо NULL либо значение, которое присутствует в таблице Teams в поле id. Причем при удалении записи из Teams если у каких то записей Players есть id удаляемой записи, он будет заменен на NULL. А constraint просто назначает имя для этого ключа

Answer (score 3):

`CONSTRAINT` - ключевое слово, которое указывает, что в данной секции описывается **ограничение**, которое налагается на данные в таблице, и которое будет проверяться подсистемой контроля целостности и непротиворечивости данных сервера, что в свою очередь не позволит внести или изменить данные в таблице так, чтобы это условие не выполнялось, а при выявлении факта наличия не соответствующих этому условию данных в таблице она будет считаться повреждённой. Сразу после этого ключевого слова указывается уникальный идентификатор (имя) этого ограничения (он может быть пропущен, тогда сервер сгенерирует его автоматически).

`REFERENCES` - ключевое слово, которое указывает, что для каждой записи таблицы значение выражения описанного непосредственно перед ним индекса будет контролироваться на наличие в точности совпадающего по значению, включая деление на фрагменты при наличии такового, значения в *уникальном* индексном выражении таблицы, указанном непосредственно после этого ключевого слова. Контроль выполняется подсистемой контроля целостности и непротиворечивости данных сервера. Любые действия, которые приведут к нарушению такого соответствия, будут блокироваться. При выявлении любого несоответствия данные будут считаться повреждёнными.

Answer (score 1):

Это ограничение, в данном случае внешний ключ. То есть значение поля `TeamId` ограничивается значениями содержащимися в поле `Id`, таблицы `Teams`, либо значением `NULL`.